# Java equivalent objective-c UITableView or UICollectionView

Tags: java, ios

what does Java use to display data like a UITable? I am building a Java program and want to customize the GUI to look like square cells. I have found a JTable so far, but I am not sure if the JTable would be able to emulate this GUI:

(I guess this would be more like a UICollectionView, but you get the idea)

What could I use in Java?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is Android your target?

Comment: I wish... It's for a standard Java program. I'm using eclipse

Comment: Java also has JList... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html